# Average of sales every 3 months in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, average, moving-average

I want every 3 month of average sales in pyspark .

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOS84.png)
Input:

```
Product Date    Sales
A   01/04/2020  50
A   02/04/2020  60
A   01/05/2020  70
A   05/05/2020  80
A   10/06/2020  100
A   13/06/2020  150
A   25/07/2020  160
```

output:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJVDy.png)

```
Product Date    Sales   3month Avg sales
A   01/04/2020   50     36.67
A   02/04/2020   60     36.67
A   01/05/2020   70    86.67
A   05/05/2020   80    86.67
A   10/06/2020  100    170
A   13/06/2020  150    170
A   25/07/2020  160    186.67
```

Avg of july is sales of (may+june+july)/3=560/3=186.67

Comment: input and output are the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the dense_rank is quite expensive and so I have calculated the custom index and to similar steps with @Cena.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w = Window.partitionBy('Product').orderBy('index').rangeBetween(-2, 0)

df.withColumn('Date', to_date('Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy')) \
  .withColumn('index', (year('Date') - 2020) * 12 + month('Date')) \
  .withColumn('avg', sum('Sales').over(w) / 3) \
  .show()

+-------+----------+-----+-----+------------------+
|Product|      Date|Sales|index|               avg|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+------------------+
|      A|2020-04-01|   50|    4|36.666666666666664|
|      A|2020-04-02|   60|    4|36.666666666666664|
|      A|2020-05-01|   70|    5| 86.66666666666667|
|      A|2020-05-05|   80|    5| 86.66666666666667|
|      A|2020-06-10|  100|    6|             170.0|
|      A|2020-06-13|  150|    6|             170.0|
|      A|2020-07-25|  160|    7|186.66666666666666|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: if the sales has happened in future also can i replace "year" is enough or anything ?

Comment: The index is just linear value for any yearmonth and 2020 is just an offset. You don't need to change anything, I think.

Comment: Hi @Lamanus  , I have added next year date to the input . it delivered right results for this year and previous years but it getting some wrong results. for next year

Comment: Oh.. the year and 2020 should be changed the order. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **dense_rank()** over the month column to compute the moving average. Cast the date and extract the month from it. `dense_rank()` rank over the month gives you consecutive ranks.

For the moving average, you can use `rangeBetween(-2, 0)` to look back 2 months from the current month. Sum by `sales` and divide by 3 for the output.

Your df:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

row = Row("Product", "Date", "Sales")
df = sc.parallelize([row("A", "01/04/2020", 50),row("A", "02/04/2020", 60),row("A", "01/05/2020", 70),row("A", "05/05/2020", 80),row("A", "10/06/2020", 100),row("A", "13/06/2020", 150),row("A", "25/07/2020", 160)]).toDF()
```

```
df = df.withColumn('date_cast', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy')).cast(DateType()))
df = df.withColumn('month', month("date_cast"))

w=Window().partitionBy("Product").orderBy("month")
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(w))

w2 = (Window().partitionBy(col("Product")).orderBy("rank").rangeBetween(-2, 0))

df.select(col("*"), ((F.sum("Sales").over(w2))/3).alias("mean"))\
        .drop("date_cast", "month", "rank").show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----------+-----+------------------+
|Product|      Date|Sales|              mean|
+-------+----------+-----+------------------+
|      A|01/04/2020|   50|36.666666666666664|
|      A|02/04/2020|   60|36.666666666666664|
|      A|01/05/2020|   70| 86.66666666666667|
|      A|05/05/2020|   80| 86.66666666666667|
|      A|10/06/2020|  100|             170.0|
|      A|13/06/2020|  150|             170.0|
|      A|25/07/2020|  160|186.66666666666666|
+-------+----------+-----+------------------+
```